# RTPEngine transcode Opus to PCMU - unable to change Opus settings from defaults

Tags: transcoding, opus, opensips

I am invoking RTPEngine from OpenSIPS to transcode incoming Opus call to PCMU. I`m passing these parameters to the RTPEngine daemon:

codec-mask-opus codec-set-opus/48000/2/32000//maxplaybackrate=32000;stereo=0;useinbandfec=1;maxaveragebitrate=32000 transcode-PCMU

When the call is established, I can see (in SIP 200OK SDP fmtp field) that Opus is being told to use default values, my changes haven`t been implemented. If I try to change Opus parameters on transcoding from PCMU to Opus, it works as expected. My question is simply this - is my syntax correct or am I doing something wrong?